# Kinetic temperature and kinetic energies

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, kinetic-theory

From my understanding, kinetic temperature is related to the average *translational* kinetic energy of particles by
$$
\frac{1}{2}m\left<v^2\right> = N k_B T
$$

I have several questions regarding what this definition:

1. How is *kinetic temperature* related to *thermodynamic temperature*? This [paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1627098) seems to suggest that they are different (tried reading the paper but couldn't understand the details).
2. Are there other types of temperature (besides kinetic and thermodynamic)? How are they defined and how do they relate to one another?
3. There are other types of kinetic energies (such as rotational and vibrational kinetic energy). Is there any type of temperature that account for these kinetic energies?
4. On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_temperature), it says that "Matter at absolute zero has no remaining transferable average kinetic energy..." What sort of kinetic energy is it referring to?

If possible, try not to relate the answer too much to statistical mechanics; I am not very comfortable with SM.

Comment: Hello! Please only ask one question per post – otherwise it might get closed due to lack of focus. You can always [edit] your question or [ask](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a new one. Thanks!